# Tell AFJSONRequestSerializer (or other serializers) to log serialized data to console

Tags: afnetworking

I couldn't find this information in the docs.

How to I tell an AFJSONRequestSerializer (or any other serializer) to log the generated JSON to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to listen for either `AFNetworkingTaskDidResumeNotification` or `AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification` notifications, and log the request of the task or operation from that.

Alternatively, you could either add a log statement in an method overridden by an HTTP manager subclass, or even swizzle `AFHTTPRequestSerialization -requestBySerializingRequest:...`.